# Route port with iptables from public IP to VPN IP

Tags: debian, iptables, vpn, port-forwarding, raspbian

I'm trying to route the traffic from port 9999 on public ip to a private ip on port 99 with a VPN in the middle.
Lets imagine that I have a public ip, X.X.X.X that when i enter to port 9999 i want to forward it through a VPN.

Public IP machine has also the OpenVPN server so has: X.X.X.X eth0 and 10.0.8.1 tun0
Intermediate machine has 10.8.0.10 tun0 and 192.168.8.4 eth0
Destination machine has 192.168.8.2 and listens on port 99

The reason i need the intermediate machine is that destination machine is a CAM. As my conection to internet is under CGNAT i need to forward all the traffic of the CAM over the VPN

In the public machine i used:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9999 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.10:9999
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.8.0.10 --dport 9999 -j SNAT --to-source X.X.X.X
```

In the intermediate machine (a raspberry pi) i used:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9999 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.8.2:99
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.8.2 --dport 99 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.8.10
```

If i make a ping from 10.0.8.1 to 10.0.8.10 works so connection exist and also in the other side.

However traffic is not routed and when i enter in the browser to X.X.X.X:9999 doesn't work. Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Please hit `edit` and add the output of  `ip route` as executed on the intermediate machine (a raspberry pi). Which row matches the X.X.X.X for the return trip? Btw, welcome to the site.

Comment: It is not clear what you try to ask. What traffic do you want to route? From one public IP? Also please add netmask to all IP addresses and show all gateways on each host.